# Routing with nginx explained?

Tags: php, rest, nginx, url-rewriting

For example, if I have a PHP script `user.php` which allows me to access a user's profile page, how do I make `/qw3rtman` load the data from `user.php?user=qw3rtman?`

I'd like a clear explanation, along with what to put into my Nginx configuration file (along with which one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well first of all, I don't usually like doing that, because usually all 404's unconditionally will be routed to `user.php` first, like `/contact` or `/home` if they don't actually exist, I usually prefer something like `/user(s)/qw3rtman` because like that I def know he's trying to access a user.

Anyways, for what you want try something like this, (assuming you don't have a default `/index.php` entry point.)

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /user.php?user=$arg_user&query_string;
}
```

Comment: Which file would I insert this in and where?

Comment: have you created a virtual host for your server or not ?, also if you are using a linux server then what is it's distro?

Comment: I haven't heard of a virtual host, so I'm assuming I haven't. I'm running on CentOS 6.5 Minimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1 last;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I'm not very familiar with nginx, hope this conf may work :)

You can learn more at [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) or [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)